# How can I read the URL-Data send with POST in Perl?

Tags: perl, forms, post, cgi, query-string

I'm trying to read out the POST-Data that was sent from a form in a page to my Perl Script. I googled and found out that:

```
read(STDIN, $param_string, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'})
```

reads out the whole Data-String with and writes the whole string to $param_string in the form of

```
Param1=Value1&Param2=Value2&Param3=Value3
```

by spliting it at the right places I get the necessary Data.

But I wonder why my $param_string is empty.

When I try the whole thing with GET:

```
$param_string = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
```

everything works fine. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There absolutely no real reason for someone at your level to want to hand parse CGI requests.

Please use [CGI::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI::Simple) or [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI).

[CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI) has a lot of baggage (HTML generation, function oriented interface) which makes [CGI::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI::Simple) preferable.

Using any CGI processing module on CPAN is better than trying to write CGI processing code from scratch.

See [`parse_query_string`](http://search.cpan.org/~andya/CGI-Simple-1.112/lib/CGI/Simple.pm#parse_query_string%28%29_Add_QUERY_STRING_data_to_%27POST%27_requests) in `CGI::Simple` for a way of accessing parameters passed using the query string when processing a form that is POSTed to your script.

If you want to learn how to do it right, you can read the source code of either module. Reading through the [CGI.pm CHANGES file](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/LDS/CGI.pm-3.48/Changes) is also instructive.

Comment: @Manni, not really.  At this point, writing CGI parsing by hand is about like writing multiplication as repeatedly adding.  It's just not anything any modern programmer should deal with, unless they want to specialize in low-level stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to retrieve GET-data but not able to retrieve POST-data, most likely you forgot to change form method from to be post. You can check your submit method by using this condition in if statement:

```
if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST"){
   read(STDIN, $param_string, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
}else {
   $param_string = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Under mod_perl 2, [Apache2::Request](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Apache2::Request) works for me.